# Multiple Parallele PHP Processes

Tags: php, email, nginx

I use Mail-in-a-Box and want to use PHP on my Website. According to https://discourse.mailinabox.email/t/is-atleast-being-able-to-toggle-php-planned/288/4 using PHP for part of the site that is responsable for the mail(Roundcube) and the main site could open security vunerability. I want to consider this advises and would for example let my server process my main site in another php process.(Or something similar...)

Note: I dont know very much about php

Here is a snippet of the nginx configuration that miab uses to enable php on specific parts of the website.

```
upstream php-fpm {
server unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
...
location ~ /mail/.*\.php {
    # note: ~ has precendence over a regular location block
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^/mail(/.*)()$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/roundcubemail/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm;

    # Outgoing mail also goes through this endpoint, so increase the maximum
    # file upload limit to match the corresponding Postfix limit.
    client_max_body_size 128M;
}
...
```

Comment: i would go a step further: let that box run email because if your wordpress site gets hacked and sends spam, your ip reputation will suffer badly. also, i’m not a fan of having lots of services running on 1 server. And mail in a box does run quite a few, all needed. i think it’s best to run tour website on a different server for the cpu and memory aspect too.

Comment: The CPU and RAM usage is no problem at all and even to to put everything in a jail is possible, but the use of a second server is for me currently not an option.

Comment: ok, then you can totally set up a new vhost on the same server. If you want to be a bit more secure, create a second php-fpm pool and set your new vhost to use that pool. Make sure it runs under a separate user as well. And you should be fine with that.